# How to get point coordinates from a plot in Mathematica v11?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have been using the points of Mathematica plots for more than 25 years and it suddenly does not work any longer in version 11:

```
gr = Plot[Sin[2 \[Pi] x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: result of the plot]

```
gr[[0]]
```

returns Graphics

```
gr[[1, 1, 1, 3]]
```

returns

```
{Directive[Opacity[1.], RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], AbsoluteThickness[1.6]], 
Line[{{2.04082*10^-8, 1.28228*10^-7}, {0.000306718, 
0.00192716}, {0.000613415, 0.00385419}, {0.00122681, 
0.0077082}, {0.0024536, 0.0154158}, {0.00490718, 
0.0308278}, {0.00981434, 0.0616262}, {0.0196287, 0.123018},....
```

The points seem to be there and reachable, but

```
gr[[1, 1, 1, 3, 2]
```

returns "Charting`Private`Tag$109972#1" instead of the Line[] with the points!

How to get the points in version 11 (and above)?

Thank you for your help.

Denis

Comment: Moving my answer to comment, probably more appropriate: it actually works for me (v11.3 on mac osx), I don't get the error: have you tried restarting the kernel? maybe you have some definitions that are creating some conflict.. but it sounds very weird

Comment: Try `gr[[1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2]]`. The actual list which contains the line primitive is wrapped by an `Annotation` that can only be seen with `FullForm` or `InputForm`. But indeed weird; these `Annotation` wrappers haven't been there in former versions.

Comment: Thank you Fraccalo. My version is 11.1 and I have the problem with a fresh Kernal and only the code above...

Comment: Thank you Enrik. gr[[1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2]] works !!! But Why?

Comment: @user3650925 As I said: The actual `Line` primitive lies a level deeper because of an (almost) invisible wrapper called `Annotation`. Have a look at `InputForm[gr[[1, 1, 1, 3]]]` to see it.

Comment: Clear. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 5):

```
Cases[gr, Line[x_] :> x, -1]
```

Comment: This is probably the most robust (and future-proof) approach possible.

Comment: ah yes, it is an interesting alternative that will work in any version. Thank you.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks for your comment, I hope so.

Comment: @user: it's not an "alternative"; it's a standard way to extract graphics primitives from a plotting function, which as noted doesn't need to know how deeply the primitves are buried in `Graphics[]`.